# What does 'that' mean here? -from Iron man 1

Tags: meaning

This scene is the very first scene of Iron man 1.

> Tony Stark: What, you're not allowed to talk? Hey, Forrest!
>
> Forrest: We can talk, sir.
>
> Tony Stark: Oh, I see. So it's personal?
>
> Woman: No, you intimidate them.
>
> Tony Stark: Good god, you're a woman. I honestly... I couldn't have
>   called that.  I mean, I'd apologize, but isn't **that** what we're going
>   for here? I thought of you as a soldier first.

I don't understand what Tony is saying: "but isn't that what we're going for here?" and "I thought of you as a soldier first."

1. Does 'that' here mean 'woman'? which therefore makes the whole line mean that they're going for a woman.
2. Does the second line mean that Tony thought she was a soldier, which is mostly man?

Comment: to call a game; a sports' metaphor, for: to say the person is a woman.

Comment: This question is unclear. Are you asking about the word *that* and what it refers to (as indicated by the question title), or something else?

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear. I edited the post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you frame the whole question, including the dialogues, still makes it look a bit confusing. But I read the script available online for the scene you're talking about to understand it clearer, since I can't watch the video right now.

The "that" you highlight means *the person looking like a soldier, first—ready to kill or defend, without giving away their gender*.

Tony must have not realized that the person talking about others being intimidated was a woman, because of the soldier outfit. Then he refuses to apologize for the mixup, by saying that **that** is what the intention of the military was, in the first place—the enemy not realizing that they are fighting with a woman (obvious physical weaknesses as compared to a man), since the weapons and protection suits neutralize most biological gender difference.

Comment: @user300475 Don't forget to mark the right answer once you feel satisfied.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not into Iron Man, but I believe the gist is that she is trying to look like a man, so no need to apologize for thinking she was a man.